# Using Unicode characters with Imagemagick and PHP

Tags: php, regex, imagemagick

I'm trying to provide text for imagemagick and it threw me a curve ball:

```
Bần chỉ là một anh nghèo
```

Per http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode, all I need to do is wrap the extended characters in  \x{}.  Using json_encode, I can easily get close:

```
print json_encode("Bần chỉ là một anh nghèo");  // Output is "B\u1ea7n ch\u1ec9 l\u00e0 m\u1ed9t anh ngh\u00e8o"
```

Now, all I need to do is to get it from `"B\u1ea7n ch\u1ec9 l\u00e0 m\u1ed9t anh ngh\u00e8o"` to `"B\x{1ea7}n ch\x{1ec9} l\x{00e0} m\x{1ed9}t anh ngh\x{00e8o}"`

Any suggestions on a regex in PHP?

EDIT: Per icktoofay's feedback, I don't think RegEx is the right solution.  I think I need to somehow execute my command differently.  My code is basically doing:

```
$cmd = "convert -fill black -font Oswald -pointsize 72 label:'" . addslashes($text) . "' logo.png"
exec($cmd);
```

Also open to any possible security holes here.  I think addslashes will do it, but...

Comment: It's trivial. What have you tried? Do you have problems with escaping the backslash in the search pattern, or with constructing the replacement pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting that example. ImageMagick takes UTF-8 input. The `\x{236A}` was part of an embedded Perl script that output to ImageMagick. Really, what you'll want to do is just hand ImageMagick some UTF-8 text.

---

Looking into it more, I'm guessing that your problem is PHP not dealing with UTF-8 command-line arguments in a sane way. I checked to see if another way (say, [`execv`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=10937)) was available, and unfortunately, there isn't. A workaround may be to write to a temporary file and use ImageMagick's `@` syntax:

```
$temp_file_name = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "txt");
file_put_contents($temp_file_name, $text);
$cmd = "convert ... label:@" . escapeshellarg($temp_file_name) . "...";
exec($cmd);
unlink($temp_file_name);
```

Comment: I actually tried that, handing the string as-is via "$cmd = "convert -fill black -font Oswald -pointsize 72 label:'" . addslashes($text) . "' logo.png";"   The code does work, but it chews up extended characters.  My next step was to try and convert $text as shown in the ImageMagick example..

Comment: BTW, I think you're right.  I tried it command-line and it output "B\x{1ea7}n ch\x{1ec9} l\x{00e0} m\x{1ed9}t anh ngh\x{00e8o}" almost literally.  So I think I'm on the wrong path...

Comment: @Anthony: You could try having ImageMagick read the text from a file rather than from the command line. I updated my answer to show this possibility.

Comment: Brilliant!  I'll give that a try and report back.  I didn't think about that approach..

Comment: I changed the code to write to disk, but I'm still getting the same results.  When I vim the file, however, I see "Báº§n chá» lÃ  má»t anh nghÃ¨o".  Perhaps I need to do something about the PHP string encoding?  If I just do a "print $text;" it shows up in the browser correctly, but apparently there is something I'm missing about encoding...

Comment: @Anthony: You'll need to figure out what encoding it is, then. In many browsers, you can tell the browser to interpret the page as a specific encoding. (In Firefox, for example, that's in View → Character Encoding.) Go through the list until it's correctly interpreted. Then you know that that's the right encoding. Then use [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/iconv) to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I tried this and verified that the encoding is UTF-8.  I think I've actually tracked down the problem: I'm ripping down the font from Google Fonts and using a python script to convert the WOFF download to a TTF file, which I then pass to ImageMagick.  I verified that "Bần chỉ là một anh nghèo" renders properly at http://www.google.com/webfonts for "Open Sans", but when  I rip it down and download the converted TTF file, it lacks some of the extended latin characters.  So I think something about my conversion process needs to change.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Anthony: No need to convert — Google Web Fonts supports TTF natively! The CSS file you'd link in — `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans` — varies its content depending on the `User-Agent` fetching it. Fetch it with cURL and you'll get a version with a link to a TrueType font. When I do that, I get [this font](http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3aCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf).

Comment: I actually struggled with this.  I saw that based on how I grabbed the font, I'd get a TTF vs WOFF.  I grabbed your link, installed it, and it seems less robust than the Google Font.  Try this: Check the font you linked to me in Character Map vs visiting http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans.  You'll notice there are way more glyphs on the web font.  Is TTF more limited?  (Note: The characters from my sample are at http://www.unicodemap.org/search.asp?search=B%E1%BA%A7n%20ch%E1%BB%89%20l%C3%A0%20m%E1%BB%99t%20anh%20ngh%C3%A8o, itemized individualy)

Comment: @Anthony: I just checked and the TTF does have all of those characters.

Comment: Well, I posted the phrase into MS Word and changed the font to Open Sans - it appears normally.  But if I launch Character Map and try to find some of the extended latin characters, like http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x1EA7/index.html, I can't find them.  Also, I copied the TTF to the server and tried to use it with ImageMagick.  The same extended characters won't show up..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24296/discussion-between-anthony-and-icktoofay)